# Need a clarification on creating dynamic html table using js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a dynamic table using html and js. I put the below code and its not working. I can do that in many number of ways. But i want know why this code is not working.

This is my code

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'ssss'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bbbb'
  }
]
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = `<table><tr><th>S.no</th><th>title</th></tr>`;

data.forEach(item => {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.name + "</td></tr>";
  console.log(item);
});

console.log("ssss");
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "</table>";
```

```html
<p id="test">
</p>
```

I got the output as below

```
 S.no   title
 1ssss2bbbb
```

My expected output is

```
 S.no   title
 1      ssss
 2      bbbb
```

Comment: Don't put partial html into `innerHTML`, the browser is going to do syntax error correction and close the tags automatically before you add the next parts.

Comment: insetad of `innerHTML` use `document.createElement('myelementTagName')` and then put your finished`html code` instead of partial code.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `</table>` into the HTML string from the beginning.

`test` is a `<p>` element, not a `table` element. Select the `table` element instead, which is a direct descendant of the `<p>`.

If you're confusing yourself, it'll be clearer if you extract the elements into descriptive variable names first, like this:

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'ssss'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bbbb'
  }
]
const p = document.getElementById("test");
p.innerHTML = `<table><tr><th>S.no</th><th>title</th></tr></table>`;
const table = p.children[0];

data.forEach(item => {
  table.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.name + "</td></tr>";
});
```

```html
<p id="test">
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that we can do that using children. I want to know actual reason behind it. without closing table tag it will automatically out the close tag?

Comment: Right, when you assign to `innerHTML`, the browser parses the string as best as it knows how - accessing the `innerHTML` of an element will never return *invalid* HTML (such as HTML with a missing close tag).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set table after all work done like this:

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'ssss'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bbbb'
  }
]
var x = `<table><tr><th>S.no</th><th>title</th></tr>`;

data.forEach(item => {
  x += "<tr><td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.name + "</td></tr>";
});

x += "</table>";
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x
console.log(x)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <p id="test">
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set id for [`<tbody>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp) part of the table and set the `innerHTML` with `js` like below:

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'ssss'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bbbb'
  }
]
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = `<table><tr><th>S.no</th><th>title</th></tr><tbody id="tableBody"></tbody></table>`;

data.forEach(item => {
  document.getElementById("tableBody").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.name + "</td></tr>";
  console.log(item);
});

console.log("ssss");
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "</table>";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <p id="test" />

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your approach a bit:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="test">

      </table>
    </p>
    <script>

 let data = [{
     id: 1,
     name: 'ssss'
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     name: 'bbbb'
   }
 ]
 var table = document.createElement('table');
 var thead = document.createElement('thead');
 var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
 var tr = document.createElement('tr');
 var td = document.createElement('td');
 var columns = ['S.No','Title'];
 var tcol = [];
 
 //creating the header while assuming all the headers are present in 1st row
 Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(col=>{
 tcol.push(col);
 });
 for(var i=0;i<columns.length;i++)
 {
    var th = document.createElement('th');
   th.innerHTML = columns[i];
   tr.appendChild(th);
 }
 
  
 thead.appendChild(tr);
 //appending the created headers to the table object
 table.appendChild(thead);

 //creating the body
 data.forEach(item => {
   tr = document.createElement('tr');
   for (var i = 0; i < tcol.length; i++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
     td.innerHTML = item[tcol[i]];
     tr.appendChild(td);
   }
   //appending the created row to the table body 
   tbody.appendChild(tr);
 });
 table.appendChild(tbody);

 //finally putting the table's html to your desired div 
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = table.outerHTML;

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

I have made an assumption that your 1st row will mostly have a columns in it if not try to pass the columns as a seperate entity.